# Powershell script won't run file from cmd.exe with given parameters

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have the following script, and it completes all the commands EXCEPT running cmd.exe with the file/parameters given...it does not error, and it completes removing the file from the temp folder afterwards.  Any idea how to get "file.exe" to run with the parameters "Location=(user-selected location code) /s" from a command line via powershell script?

```
# Get the Computer ID.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "'Enter Computer ID"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Please enter the Computer ID."
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$textBox.MaxLength = 8
$form.Controls.Add($textBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $Machine = $textBox.Text
    $Machine
}

# Get the Location Code.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form1.Text = "Select a Location"
$form1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(190,250) 
$form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,180)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form1.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form1.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(85,180)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Please select a Location Code:"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20) 
$listBox.Height = 140

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("01")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("02")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("03")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("04")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("06")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("07")

$form1.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form1.Topmost = $True

$result1 = $form1.ShowDialog()

if ($result1 -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $Server = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $Server
}

# Ensure the Computer ID is available on the Network before continuing.
IF (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1){
    Try {
        $destination = "\\" + $Machine + "\C$\temp\"
        $source = "\\server\location\folder\file name 1.1.EXE"
        New-Item -Path  $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination  -Force | Out-Null
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ArgumentList $Server -ScriptBlock {
            $file = "C:\temp\file name 1.1.EXE"
            $renfile = "C:\temp\file.exe"
            $execfile = "C:\temp\file.exe Location="+($args[0]).ToString()+" /s"
            Rename-Item $file $renfile
            & cmd.exe /c $execfile | Out-Null
            Remove-Item $renfile -Force
            }
        $status = "Success"
        }
    Catch {
        $status = "Failed"
        }
    "$Machine, $status" | out-file -filepath c:\temp\result2.csv -Append -Encoding ascii

    }
ELSE{
    #Sets status to "Not on Network" if the Test-Connection failed. Indicates the PC is not on the Network currently"
    $status = "Not on Network"
}
```

Note: The following code block works fine, but is designed for a .txt file of computer names, as opposed to a GUI where the user can enter a location and computer ID individually:

```
Get-Content C:/temp/faillist.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $source = "\\server\location\folder\file name 1.1.EXE"
        $destination = "\\" + $_ + "\C$\temp\"
        New-Item -Path  $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        Copy-Item -path $source -Destination $destination  -force | Out-Null
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
            & cmd.exe /c "C:\temp\file name 1.1.EXE" Location=02 /s | Out-Null
            }
        $file = $destination + "file name 1.1.EXE"
        Remove-Item $file -Force
        $status = "Success"
        }
    Catch {
        $status = "Failed"
        }
    "$_, $status" | out-file -filepath c:\temp\result2.csv -Append -Encoding ascii
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `cmd /c` in a PS script?

Comment: /c isn't really necessary...doing silent installs on remote machines...and this is the way we were given by the software vendor (has to be installed from CLI with given switches...otherwise will not install)...janky, I know.

Comment: All arguments to the script will be strings by default.  I'd suggest having a `Param()` block to capture the location rather than `$args[0]`.  I'll post a suggested alternative

Comment: As I'm still quite ignorant to powershell, and used a template to make the "GUI" portion of this...is it possible to use the param block in a similar manner (goal is to use ps2exe to make this an executable GUI for users)?

Also, thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Do users execute this from the command line?  You can get input from a Windows Form and store it into a variable for use if that's your future plan is to prompt for the location instead.

Comment: If ran locally, then yes, "c:\temp\file.exe Location=(location code) /s" is executed from the command line.  I'm attempting to make an .exe with this powershell script so we don't have to run this locally on each machine...and it will have 2 windows forms.  One for computer ID, one for location ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory)]
  [String]$Location
)

<# ... #>

& 'C:\Temp\File.exe' Location="$Location" /s >$Null
```

Alternatively:

```
$Proc = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Temp\File.exe' -ArgumentList @("Location=$Location",'/s') -NoNewWindow -Wait -WindowStyle 'Hidden' -PassThru
```

In this method, you can capture the process details, like exitcode, and have further action e.g. `$Proc.ExitCode`